# Get sub site path with Client object model (Silverlight)

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, silverlight

I'm currently building a Silverlight web part on SharePoint 2010. The issue I have, maybe is too trivial for me, is that I have a list, lets say its http://www.mysite.com/subsite/anothersubsite/Lists/mylist/AllItems.aspx, I want to retrieve the site url, in this case: http://www.mysite.com/subsite/anothersubsite . The url can vary depending on the depth of the subsite. I've try using the ClientContext.Current but without success.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the required properties. Unlike server side object model, context.web will be largely empty until you explicitly load the data.

```
context = ClientContext.Current;   
web = context.Web;
context.Load(web, w => w.Title, w => w.Description, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl);   
context.ExecuteQueryAsync(OnSiteLoadSuccess, OnSiteLoadFailure);
```

So here you can access web.ServerRelativeUrl method in OnSiteLoadSuccess method.

Comment: I've tried that, but always return the root "/" as ServerRelativeUrl. I think my issue is that the XAP file is hosted in the http://www.mysite.com/SomeFolder/MyApp.xap and return always the root based on this address, not from where the webpart is.